# Trouble with moving to a Responsive Template

Tags: html, wordpress, responsive-design, wordpress-theming

I am trying to update my website www.trickmypup.org to a responsive theme("striker") using a wordpress add on through hostgator. The problem I am facing is when I switch to the responsive theme the tables on my pages: Basic, Easy, Moderate, and Hard get completely messed up.

Is there a way for me to set a max image size for those photos only? Or a code that will keep it in a similar format to what I have now?

Comment: Please review: http://tinyurl.com/sodebug/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set a fixed width in your table.

Instead of 100%:

```
<div class="entry-content">
        <table style="background-color: #ffffff;" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
```

you could try to set it in pixels. For example 570px; as shown:

```
<div class="entry-content">
        <table style="background-color: #ffffff;" width="570px" border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
```

Comment: btw. your google analytics token isn't set correctly. There is this error on your website: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://d2dq2ahtl5zl1z.cloudfront.net/analytics.js/v1/YOUR_API_TOKEN/analytics.min.js`